# Java Scanner empty command issue

Tags: java

I use a `Scanner` to get inputs from the console in my Java project with this simple code:

```
char com = ' ';
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
com = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

When I enter my expected commands (a,b,c,d...), it works fine, but if I push the Enter button of my keyboard without command entered, I have this error message and the app crash:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 0

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Capture the string and parse it independently instead.

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
String line = sc.nextLine();
while(line.equals("")) {
    System.out.println("Nothing entered - try again!");
    line = sc.nextLine();
}
com = line.charAt(0);
```

The reason it fails is due to the `nextLine` consuming the newline character; if you enter nothing, then the string will be considered empty as read by `nextLine`.  You want to detect this and allow the user to re-enter the value until they enter something that's not an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

```
sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

This get's the 0th character of a String (the first letter of the String).

If you don't enter anything, the String will obviously be empty, so when trying to access the index 0, it will throw a StringIndexOutOfBoundsException.

Answer (score 0):

You need to define an **individual** variable that is equal to the user input.

i.e.:

```
String individualvariable = sc.nextLine();
```

Then, use `individualvariable` with .equals to compare strings. In simple terms, you can't just do `com = sc.nextLine()` first, define com (string, int, boolean), and define a variable of what `sc.nextLine()` is equal to (x, y, etc.) ; **then** compare the two variables.

This makes the code easy to read, so take my earlier example and split it up:

```
String individualvariable;

com = sc.nextLine();

while(individualvariable .equals (com))
{

}
```

That second block of code I gave you should be the easiest to read, and most simple.